# How methods of Object class be visible through interface?

Tags: java

```
interface A {

    void hi();  
}

class AImpl implements A {

 public void hi() {

        System.out.println("hi");
    }

    public void to() {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}    

public class InterfaceTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        A a = new AImpl();
        a.hi();
        System.out.println(a.hashCode());
        //a.to();
    }
}
```

here interface A has no inheritance relationship with Object class but all the mehods of Object class can be access through the interface.
why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Java Language Specification section 9.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/interfaces.html#9.2):

> The members of an interface are:
>
> - Those  members declared in the interface.
> - Those members inherited from direct superinterfaces.
> - If an interface has no direct superinterfaces, then the interface implicitly declares a public
>     abstract member method m with
>     signature s, return type r, and throws
>     clause t corresponding to each public
>     instance method m with signature s,
>     return type r, and throws clause t
>     declared in Object, unless a method
>     with the same signature, same return
>     type, and a compatible throws clause
>     is explicitly declared by the
>     interface. It is a compile-time error
>     if the interface explicitly declares
>     such a method m in the case where m is
>     declared to be final in Object.

The third bullet is the important one - basically interfaces which don't extend any other interfaces automatically inherit `hashCode` etc.