# Interfaces implicitly declaring public methods of Object class?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, jls

According to [The Java Language Specification, Java SE 16 Edition (JLS) §9.2 *Interface Members*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.2):

> If an interface has no direct superinterface types, then the interface implicitly declares a `public abstract` member method `m` with signature `s`, return type `r`, and `throws` clause `t` corresponding to each `public` instance method `m` with signature `s`, return type `r`, and `throws` clause `t` declared in `Object` ([§4.3.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2)), unless an `abstract` method with the same signature, same return type, and a compatible `throws` clause is explicitly declared by the interface.

Why does any top-level Interface “implicitly” declare the public methods of the **Object** class? What is the purpose of this design?

Comment: Everything is an `Object`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Which is not true for Java, look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11844096

Comment: I know it is like this, but I have not found a compelling reason for me why this choice was made in this manner. What I dislike the most is the lack of restriction like this: `Set<? extends InterfactWithHashCodeAndEquals>`. You can't do this at compile time, so you can pass _any_ Object into a set. Even if they did not override `equals/hashCode` _on purpose_. Or the fact that _any_ object can be used as a synchronizer

Comment: @Eugene yep, for better or for worse. All programming languages have quirks, some more fundamental than others. However, rememeber: generics _didn't even exist_ in Java until 2004, when Java had already been around for over a decade. It was something added to the language more than ten years after the fundamentals had already been firmly and irrevocably established.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the purpose of this design?

Because you want to be able to call all the [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html) methods ( [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#toString()), [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)), [`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()), and such) on every object of any type.

```
interface Foo {
  
}

Foo foo = ...;

foo.equals(otherFoo);
```

Doesn't matter if I actually declared the `equals` method in the interface.

Comment: But the JLS states that these methods are not inherited from the Object class - then how will it be useful? The class when implementing interface always inherits the method override definition from the Superclass rather than SuperInterface - so it is ultimately definition of Object class that will operate for any top level class only implementing an interface and not extending any other class explicitly As mentioned [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#:~:text=First%2C%20methods%20inherited,the%20class%20hierarchy.).

Comment: @theutonium.18 As you can see: I don't use any class. I access the `equals` method of the interface, which is implicitly given and the execution is propagated to the actual implementation. Interfaces provide a layer of abstraction and those implicit methods are there to make out lives easier. Imagine you had to add `toString` to every interface where you want to use it. If that would be the case, I would have switched to another language because it's too much boilerplate code to write.

Comment: But then using this concept - how will you explain  the invocation of `final` methods that are inherited from the `Object` class?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Interfaces do **not** inherit from `Object` class. They just implicitly provide the same methods, that propagate to the actual implementation. You should see it like this: Interfaces are just an abstraction that should make developers lives easier. You could create a copy of the Java language and remove interfaces completely, it will still work the same as with interfaces, but it will make development (and especially refactoring) harder. Interfaces are just a another layer to hide implementation details and group classes with common behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot Benjamin .. I got the sense of your answer - it is basically to make sure that methods of Object class are made accessible to all the subclasses - that implicitly interface adds the public methods of the `Object` class.

Comment: Right. And it's also "convenience": Similar to "every class extends Object". The Java devs could have made this explicit, so you had to write `extends Object` for every class. The same applies for interfaces: They could have made this explicit, too, so you had to add all `Object` methods to every interface. Both cases would have been a pretty boring writing exercise. And there are many more cases with similar behavior, like when you `extends XYZ`, you don't have to repeat all the method definitions, it's done implicitly for you. High level programming was made to write and repeat **less** code

Comment: I think your comments address the question better than the answer, but still, it correctly addresses it nevertheless. I sometimes (with my limited lenses on jdk), wish that neither the interfaces nor objects would have these common methods. 1+.

Comment: @Eugene I guess without those "default" methods lot's of Java frameworks wouldn't work properly, or get much slower due to heavy use of reflection. I'd say at least `getClass` is really mandatory. In the past 20 years the Java dev realized that some decisions from the past weren't the best. That's why `finalize` get's deprecated in Java 17. But on the other hand Java made a promise 25 years ago: Backwards compatibility. You still should be able to run code from 1996 on your current JVM. That's why they can't change the whole language and ecosystem with every release like other languages do.

Comment: Also found this related question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408730/how-methods-of-object-class-be-visible-through-interface

Answer (score 1):

## Every class is implicitly a subclass of `Object`

See:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html for more

> Definitions: A class that is derived from another class is called a subclass (also a derived class, extended class, or child class). The class from which the subclass is derived is called a superclass (also a base class or a parent class).

> Excepting Object, which has no superclass, every class has one and only one direct superclass (single inheritance). In the absence of any other explicit superclass, every class is implicitly a subclass of Object.

> Classes can be derived from classes that are derived from classes that are derived from classes, and so on, and ultimately derived from the topmost class, Object. Such a class is said to be descended from all the classes in the inheritance chain stretching back to Object.

Comment: But if you consider  (JLS:9.4.1.2): Second, interfaces do not inherit from Object, but rather implicitly declare many of the same methods as Object (§9.2). So, there is no common ancestor for the toString declared in Object and the toString declared in an interface. At best, if both were candidates for inheritance by a class, they would conflict. Working around this problem would require awkward commingling of the class and interface inheritance trees.

Comment: @Basil - I think based on the artilcle extract I mentioned above - why is it being mentioned that both do not need to have common ancestors?

Comment: Here is the link to the excerpt : [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#:~:text=Second%2C%20interfaces%20do,interface%20inheritance%20trees.). Please use Chrome browser for it to highlight exact portion.

Comment: I don't understand this answer at all. The question is : "why **interfaces**..." and your answer is : "every **class**...", that you even highlight. This makes no sense.

Comment: @Eugene Now I see the point made by you and theutonium.18. My first reading was too fast and shallow. I now agree this Answer does not actually address the Question  with regard to *interfaces* rather than *classes*.

Comment: @BasilBourque right. the other, accepted answer, is correct, imo.